# ActiveMQ memory leak - Understanding objects in the heap

Tags: java, memory-leaks, activemq-classic

My ActiveMQ heap size is increasing continuously and it runs out of memory eventually. Took the heap dump for one instance which is still running and got the following classes having a lot of instances (rest of the classes are pretty minimal). Looking for pointers as to what might be going wrong here.

```
170866 instances of class org.apache.activemq.command.ProducerId
170526 instances of class org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.AnnotatedMBean
170519 instances of class org.apache.activemq.command.SessionId
170518 instances of class org.apache.activemq.command.ConnectionId
170482 instances of class org.apache.activemq.broker.ProducerBrokerExchange
170482 instances of class org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.ProducerView
170482 instances of class org.apache.activemq.command.ProducerInfo
170482 instances of class org.apache.activemq.state.ProducerState
```

**Code snippet for sending the message:**

```
MessageProducer messageProducer = session.createProducer(topic);
messageProducer.setTimeToLive(5 * 60 * 1000);
Message message = session.createObjectMessage(agentDebugEvent);
messageProducer.send(message);
```

Is it because `messageProducer.close()` is missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are creating producers for each message send and never closing them there will be a build up of JMX MBeans for those producers as each is exposed in the JMX tree in order to manage and debug what they are doing.  You can of course turn off JMX and that would lower the overhead but you would still slowly creep towards an eventual death of the Broker as it still needs to track the attached producers.

If you want to do something like this (and I don't know why you would) you could switch to the JMS Pool and that would do some pooling of resources such that you could appear to create a producer per send and it would simply use a cached anonymous producer.  In reality though this is a generally poor design and you should evaluate why you think you need to be doing something along these lines.

Creating a MessageProducer is a costly operation involving round-tripping over the network, creating broker side resource such as MBeans etc.  If you are looking for performance in your senders, then create one producer and keep reusing it.

Comment: I think not closing the producer was a bug in the code i had. Does using a single producer for all messages have any advantage over creating a new producer every time i have to send a message?

Comment: Creating a consumer is a heavyweight operation, if you want performant sends then use a single producer.